# CodeIgniter: jQuery post and load next page

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I am successfully able to save the input value using ajax post but it is not loading the next page.

Client Side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notifyEmail() {

      var form_data = {
                  'email':$('#inviteEmail').val()
                };
        alert($('#inviteEmail').val());
      $.ajax({
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('main/email_invites'); ?>",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: form_data,
                  success: function(msg) {
                    return true;
                  }
            });
    }
  </script>

<input type='text' id='inviteEmail' placeholder='Enter email'/>
        <a href='#' name='email' id='invite-all' onclick='notifyEmail();' class='btn'>Notify Me</a>
```

Controller Code:

```
function email_invites()
    {
        $this->load->model('emailInvites');
        if($query = $this->emailInvites->saveEmailInvite())
        {
                $this->load->view('emailInvites');

        }
    }
```

Comment: for one thing, you've got `$query =` instead of `$query ==`. Was that intentional? For another, you're posting by AJAX, which means you will have to use Javascript to load the next page after the POST completes (in your `success` function). Right now you're just returning a bunch of HTML to your success function, you're not redirecting the user.

Comment: Assignment sign was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. How would redirect user using jQuery ajax?

Comment: Easy way to do it: Instead of `$this->load->view(...`, just echo some string like `'ok'`. Then in your success, make sure that `msg` == `'ok'`. If yes, `window.location.href = 'new_url'`. If not, alert the user somehow that the post failed.

Comment: By the way, if you're just submitting the form and then immediately loading a new page, there is no need at all to use AJAX. Just make the form action `site_url('main/email_invites')` so it submits directly to that controller.

Comment: I am using Ajax submission for client side form validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is the following which could help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notifyEmail() {

      var form_data = {
                  'email':$('#inviteEmail').val()
                };
        alert($('#inviteEmail').val());
      $.ajax({
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('main/email_invites'); ?>",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: form_data,
                  dataType:'json',
                  success: function(msg) {
                    if(msg.response)
                       //load the content in the body or wherever you want  
                       jQuery('body').load("<?php echo site_url('main/email_invites/show'); ?>"); 
                    else
                       console.log("Opps, Something wrong happend"); 
                    return true;
                  }
            });
    }
  </script>


    <input type='text' id='inviteEmail' placeholder='Enter email'/>
    <a href='#' name='email' id='invite-all' onclick='notifyEmail();' class='btn'>Notify Me</a>
```

**In the controller**

```
function email_invites($action = 'process')
    {
        if($action == 'process')
        {
               $this->load->model('emailInvites');
               $query['response'] = $this->emailInvites->saveEmailInvite(); 
               echo json_encode($query); 


        }
        else
        {
              $this->load->view('emailInvites');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to echo the url, just use it in ajax call like this,

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'main/email_invites',
              type: 'POST',
              data: form_data,
              success: function(msg) {
                return true;
              }
        });
```

If `site_url` method returns the required url, then the ajax call needs to be,

```
 $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo site_url('main/email_invites'); ?>",
              type: 'POST',
              data: form_data,
              success: function(msg) {
                return true;
              }
        });
```